# Measuring current with ammeter. Circuit doesn't works anymore

Tags: current

I have a very basic ammeter (UNI-T UT33D). It has 3 connector: the COM and 200mA/V/Res and finally a probe for 10A Max.

I know that current need to be measured in series.

If I interrupt my circuit (9V battery + blue led) positioning the ammeter in series and with probe on 200mA/V port, the LED doesn't lite and I read 000 on screen, whatever scale I'm using.

If I put the probe on 10A, the LED lights and I read 0.01 on screen.

Too little current? The fuse and the battery of ammeter is ok.

Is it normal that the circuit doesn't work? I don't think... Thank you

EDIT

I did buy a set of 10 fuse fast blown. All ok. Now I can measure the current and the led is lite with ammeter in serie.

I did check old fusible with continuity test with the ammeter... dead.

Thank you

Comment: 200mA input is fused, while 10A is not. In some prevoius measurement you or who ever used the multimeter may have blown the fuse. Open (very carefully) the device and replace the fuse with same type and rating.

Comment: So, a circuit that doesn't work == fuse blown? It seems sane... seems...

Comment: @sineverba - it is not just that circuit does not work - Todor has used his experience to know what most meters fuse the low current ranges but not the high-current ranges. The circuit worked when the meter was set to the 10A range.

Comment: You never told us how much current does the LED draw. Do you have a series resistor to define the current? It could also be that your circuit needs more than 200 mA.

Comment: @nickagian he says on 10A range there is 0.01 on the screen - so the current is about 10mA (between 5mA and 14mA).

Comment: @TodoSimeonov: Oops. You are correct. Didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: @sineverba if you are 100% sure that the 0.2A fuse is good, then it may be some other internal fault of the multimeter. Most of these internal faults are hard to repair (more than the cost of a new multimeter). What is the rating of the fuse you say is OK - 0.2A or 10A?

Comment: I did buy today a set of 10 new fuses. I will try to change it. My multimetes has only 1 fuse on 250mA max reading. After replace, I could check also the fuse with continuity test of ammeter itself. I will after my attempts. Thank you

Comment: @TodorSimeonov you was right. Thank you very much.

Comment: 200mA full scale for say 2V ful scale implies current shunt may be 10 Ohms which is about the same ESR as  5mm LED and if you failed to add a current limiting R then the 200mA cct. fuse is blown while the 10A cct indicates 0.01 A.  Everyone blows a fuse eventually, unless you are very very careful when learning how to use it.